# get k8s pods from a node with regex pattern match in namespace name

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, kubectl

Team,

I am able to fetch all pods running on a node with its namespace but my namespaces are generated dynamically and they change with characters in end. is there a way i can include a regex/pattern that I can use in kubectl command to pull all pods from all matching namespace?

```
kubectl get pods -n team-1-user1 --field-selector=spec.nodeName=node1,status.phase=Running
```

actual output1: works

```
NAMESPACE                                     NAME                                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
team-1-user1                                   calico-node-9j5k2                                                      1/1     Running   2          104d
team-1-user1                                   kube-proxy-ht7ch                                                       1/1     Running   2          130d
```

I want below pulling pods for all namespaces starting with "team-".

```
kubectl get pods -n team-* --field-selector=spec.nodeName=node1,status.phase=Running
```

actual output2: fails

```
No resources found in team-workflow-2134-asf-324-d.yaml namespace.
```

expected outout: want this..

```
NAMESPACE                                     NAME                                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
team-1-user1                                   calico-node-9j5k2                                                      1/1     Running   2          104d
team-1-user1                                   kube-proxy-ht7ch                                                       1/1     Running   2          130d

team-2-user1                                   calico-node-9j5k2                                                      1/1     Running   2          1d
team-2-user1                                   kube-proxy-ht7ch                                                       1/1     Running   2          10d
```

Comment: No, you can't glob or regex that. What you could do is query using labels. Something like `kubectl get pods -l mylabel=myvalue --all-namespaces`

Comment: but my namespaces does not list under labels or i did not understand the suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

You can pipe the output of `kubectl get pods` into `awk` and match a regex for the same:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "team-") print $0}'
```

Here's a sample output for the same, searching for pods in `kube-` namespace:

```
❯❯❯ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "kube-") print $0}'
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-27wxs                     1/1   Running             0     107s
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-ztgq8                     1/1   Running             0     106s
kube-system            etcd-minikube                                1/1   Running             0     109s
kube-system            kube-addon-manager-minikube                  1/1   Running             0     108s
```

Comment: so there is no way to do expansion in kubectl then?

Comment: @AhmFM No, I would recommend planning your labeling ahead of time.

Comment: Labels are the preferred approach, but this will serve for time being & if you haven't planned on the usage of labels in advance

Comment: but my namespaces does not list under labels or i did not understand the suggestion.

Comment: you can assign labels to each pod and then use them to select the pods having a specific label, you can see the current labels on pods by `kubectl get pods --show-labels`

Comment: Just to note, most resources in k8s support labels, not just pods.